# How to properly add integer values from a stack in a new function?

Tags: c, stack

I have implemented basic `push` and `pop` functions in my stack. I have a function that prints the values and tells the user if the stack is empty. If it's not, then it prints the values from the stack (code below). Now, what would be the proper way to add the values in the new function (called `add_stack_values` in the stack and display the sum? The values are randomly generated using `<time.h>`.

```
void print_stack(Stack *stack) {
    int i;
    if (stack->top == -1) {
        printf("The stack is empty");
    }
    else {
        printf ("Stack:\n");
        for (i = 0; i <= stack->top; ++i) {
            add_stack_values(stack);
            printf(" %d\n", stack->item[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The stack is declared like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int vrh, polje[MAXSTACK];
} Stack;
```

If you need any other information to answer the question, feel free to let me know and I'll edit the question.

Comment: `time.h` does not provide random values. The proper way to add integers is the `+` operator actually. IOW: it is unclear what your actual problem is. Please yhow your own effort.

Comment: If this question is about "*Please code `add_stack_values()` for me.*" I'd vote to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function add_stack_values() is supposed to get every entry in the stack (because the argument is the pointer to the stack and not each element in the stack), then you should **not** loop through the entries of the stack while calling it. If you do this you will repeat the full addition each time you got through the loop. Otherewise you could have just done the += within the loop in print_stack(). An alternative would be to have an element in the structure total_value which is updated every time you push or pop an element in the stack. In that case, you could just reference that element when you want to see it.

```
stack-> total += stack->item[i];
```

Another point is that given the call as you have it in your question, you have no way of keeping track of what the previous value was in order to add the new item unless the total is an element in the stack. In that case, you need to have a way of initializing it.

You should have it as

```
int add_stack_values(Stack *stack){
  int i, retval=0;
  if (stack->top == -1)
  {
    printf ("The stack is empty");
    /* retval = 0; is set up by initialization */
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("Stack:\n");
    for (i=0; i <= stack->top; ++i)
    {
      retval += stack->item[i];
    }
  }
  printf ("Total: %d\n", retval);
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you briefly explain me why I should not do that? Or point me to some relevant source where I can find out why?

Comment: @r3bl I expanded the answer